# Reactjs looping through object with map

Tags: reactjs

I'm not sure what kind of problem this is, but I have a `state.sports` which contains some data about sports. I added new data to this object and then I tried to render it on the DOM with this component.

```
class AddProject extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      newSport:{}
    }
    this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this);
  }

  static defaultProps = {
      Types:['air','aquatic','land']
  }
  handleSubmit(e){
    if (!this.refs.sport.value) {
      alert("title required");
    } else {
      this.setState({
        newSport:{
          sport: this.refs.sport.value,
          type: this.refs.type.value
        }
      },function() {
        this.props.addSport(this.state.newSport);
      });
    }
    e.preventDefault();
  }
  render() {
    let typeOptions = this.props.Types.map(type => {
      return <option key={type} value={type}>{type}</option>
    });        
    return (
      <div className="addproject">
        <h3>Add project </h3>
        <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
          <div>
            <label>Sport </label><br/>
            <input type="text"
              key="sport"
              ref="sport"
            placeholder="Add project" />
          </div>
          <div>
            <label>Type</label><br/>
            <select ref='type'>
              {typeOptions}
            </select>
          </div>
          <input type='submit' value='Submit' />
        </form>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
export default AddProject;
```

Then I added this formatted data into a list with this component:

```
class Project extends Component {

  render() {
    let Sports;
    //check if there is data in props.sports which is bind to state.sports
    if (this.props.sports) {
      Sports = this.props.sports.map(sport => {            
        return (
          //after some expirements i found that the key is the cause of the problem 
          <ProjectItems key={sport.name} sport={sport}  />
        );
      });
    }
    return (
      <div className="project">
        <h1>List </h1>
        <ul>
          {Sports}
        </ul>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Then ProjectItems formats the data into name of the sport and type of sport. Anyway when I enter some data it only renders the type of sport and the sport's name returns `undefined`, like [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AIvWa.png). Can you tell me what's wrong ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

maybe what you want to achieve is set a nested object properties on the state.

use this:

```
 this.setState(
        {newSport: 
           update(this.state.newSport, 
            {type: {$set: this.refs.type.value}},
            {name: {$set: this.refs.sport.value}}
                )
         });
```

the sports JSON structure will be:

```
 newSport: {type: "air", name: "land"}
```

the 
then you can display the sports:

```
 this.props.sports.map(sport => {            
        return (
//the key will not be a problem, since now it has values in it.
    <ProjectItems key={sport.name} sport={sport}  />
        );
```

Answer (score 0):

It would be more clear if you gave code of `ProjectItems` class, but at first glance it looks like in `handleSubmit` method you sholud change this:

```
newSport:{
  sport: this.refs.sport.value,
  type: this.refs.type.value
}
```

to this:

```
newSport:{
  name: this.refs.sport.value,
  type: this.refs.type.value
}
```

Comment: So it works? If so, you can mark my answer as working :)